# Emailing managers separately who were CC'ed in an email reply

Tags: communication, email, company-culture

I apologize if the question is a little convoluted, the situation is this: I'm a co-op student who emailed my manager (who is away on business) for a question that I thought was small. It turns out the question is outside her scope of knowledge and she wants me to double check with another manager and a colleague. However she CC'ed those people in her reply, so they can see the email thread.

Do I email the CC'ed individuals with my question separately, or just assume that they've seen the email thread and wait for their response? I don't want to assume anything, but at the same time I don't want to come across as repetitive/needy.

Comment: How long has it been and how urgent is the task? If it isn't urgent I'd leave it be and follow up in a couple days. If it is urgent then may as well prod them for answers now IMO

Comment: I know several managers, who receive many, many e-mails, and concluded that the only way to cope with it is to filter out automatically everything that is not addressed directly to them, their reasoning being that they will be approached in a more direct way, if their input is really needed. They would hence not even look at an e-mail, where they were just cc'ed. Do similar practices exist at your company?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the urgency of your question, I'd wait a day or so for the other individuals to respond.

If no response is forthcoming, I'd hit Reply All on your manager's response and say something like:

> Hi "Other Manager" & Colleague,
>
> Can either of you assist me with my question below?
>
> Thanks